# Angular jwt authentication with HttpOnly cookie

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcookie

We have .Net Core 5.0 backend API which is returning a jwt token wrapped in a HttpOnly cookie when I call the login API endpoint & in the response body, it is sending me user's name & userId. My question is, as it's an HttpOnly cookie, so javascript code will not be able to handle it. Then how can Angular application understand that the login is successful ?? In the subscribe method, how to get that jwt token? And in the logout method, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is a common one, like wrapping jwt into a http only cookie. On angular side you can really on response status code to know if login was successfully or not. In you case you are receiving even user information's back, you can use also those ones.

In another scenarios, after a successful login , front end will make a new call like "user-profile" to get extra user information's.

In this case you will not need that wrapped JWT, on every subsequent request on the same domain cookie will be sent by browser by default, so no need for http interceptor which append authorization headers to requests.

hope this help you, getting a better view.

Comment: Ya I know that HttpOnly cookie will get sent to server automatically on every request. But what I was asking is, should I just check whether the response of login method?? In many blogs, I have seen they are checking for the jwt token in response & then if the response has that token, they are letting users navigate to Home page. For my case then I have to only check the response body of the login method , the login method is sending me only user's name & userId, & based on that I have to let the user log in.

Comment: In you case it would be enough to check response status code, and also user name and user id. What are doing on another approach is when the jwt is send back as payload not wrapped in cookie, but is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know Angular, I will respond with what you should be doing.

JWT is used by passing it through the **Authorization** header.  This usually means that the token should be provided in a way JavaScript can access it, so you can add it using this **Authorization** header every time you `fetch()`.

Having said that, your login API's response code will tell the caller if the login was successful or not.

As per the HTTP standard (see [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication)), an authentication method should respond with **200 OK** if the authentication (log in) is successful, or **401 Unauthorized** if the log in fails.

As a backend developer, I highly recommend that you adhere to the set standards.  I would ditch the cookie option and simply return a response to the user that includes the user's information as well as the JWT.